# Next.js 14 with Prisma FindMany call not returning updated data

Tags: node.js, next.js, digital-ocean, prisma

I have a Next 14 app built using Prisma with a mySql db hosted in Azure and the site is hosted on digital ocean. When I update the database on the deployed site, I an see changes occurring in the db. However, my findMany() call seems to not be pulling in the updated data. It takes a redeploy to occur and then it pulls in the data correctly, until an update occurs.

Im at a loss on whats happening.

Example that works every time even after updates:

Route: api/campaigns/username/[...username]

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";

export async function GET(
  req: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { username: string } }
) {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        username: params.username[0],
      },
    });
    const campaigns = await prisma?.campaign.findMany({
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: "desc",
      },
      where: {
        video: { userId: user?.id },
      },
      include: {
        CampaignComment: {
          include: {
            user: {
              select: {
                username: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    if (campaigns.length === 0) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "No campaigns found." },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ campaigns: campaigns }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

The example that doesnt grab up to date data until a redeploy.

Route: api/campaigns

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const featuredCampaigns = await prisma?.campaign.findMany({
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: "desc",
      },
      where: {
        fundingComplete: false,
      },
      include: {
        CampaignComment: {
          include: {
            user: {
              select: {
                username: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    if (featuredCampaigns.length === 0) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "No campaigns found" },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ campaigns: featuredCampaigns }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: `Error: ${error}` }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I log the result to the client and am getting the old data every time that was there at deployment. Is there caching happening with Prisma or Next routes? Why would the username endpoint be grabbing new data?

TLDR: Database has updated data but FindMany() is grabbing old data everytime until redeploy. Everything works fine in Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add this to my `route.tsx`.

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```